# How to allow paragraphs in a rails text area similar to html text editors such as ckeditor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

Is there a way to to allow user to write paragraphs (with spaces) in a rails text_area similar to html text editors such as ckeditor.

```
<%= form_for(@usernote) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :note, :rows => 15, placeholder: "Create Your Note..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6):

By "spaces" do you mean new lines?

When you display the text from the database to your view, you can use the `simple_format()` view helper to re-apply the formatting the user submitted the text with.

```
#show.html.erb
<p><%= @post.title %></p>
<p><%= simple_format(@post.body) %></p>
```